# Custom Range Shard Key in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a `mongodb` configured with 3 shards, each with 3 replica and these reside on 3 physical servers.

I am trying to have data for specific date ranges on each shards;

i.e. I want data for last 3 days on one shard and data for last 6 days to 3 days on shard two and all other data on shard three.

Is it possible to define a shard key range manually like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Tag Aware Sharding.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/tag-aware-sharding/

This will let you add tags to your shards and then define ranges to the tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.I am trying to have data for specific date ranges on each shards;
```

So it is good to use **Date** as a `shard key`

> 2.I want data for last 3 days on one shard and data for last 6 days to 3
>   days on shard two and all other data on shard three.

For this purpose **Tag Aware Sharding** will help you much.

*Explanation*:

Lets assume  have 3 shards **shard1**,**shard2**,**shard3**.So first **create** the shard tags for the required shards:

> sh.addShardTag("shard1", "tag1")
>
> sh.addShardTag("shard2", "tag2")
>
> sh.addShardTag("shard3", "tag3")

where **tag1**,**tag2**,**tag3** are the tag names.Tag names are usually user-defined.

To **remove** the shard tag :

> sh.removeShardTag("shard3", "tag3")

Now you need data from **db**`(database)` in **coll**`(collection)` for last `3 days` in one shard.Then try this:

> sh.addTagRange(db.coll,{new Date(2014, 11, 11)}, {new Date(2010, 14,
>   111)}, tag1)

**P.S**: Make sure that you create the shard key on date field.

I hope this helps.

Comment: How will old data shift to shard3? Will Auto-Balancing be doing that job? How often does auto-balancing task runs? Aren't there any chances of Data Inconsistency?